# express + react CORS on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

This is the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://cheapandnice-backend.herokuapp.com/api/products/list' 
from origin 'http://cheapandnice.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access- 
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But I've already included the origin with [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors):

```
const app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.ORIGIN,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

process.env.ORIGIN is http://cheapandnice.herokuapp.com

I've tried with *heroku local*, which I think runs the code on heroku locally, and everything works just fine. As for my client I served the files locally with *"yarn build" and then "serve -d build"* and it works.

However this is what I get whem I run heroku restart and heroku logs --tail

```
2020-05-09T01:57:28.971077+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-05-09T01:57:28.987996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-05-09T01:57:35.626755+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is running on port 41637
2020-05-09T01:57:35.629379+00:00 app[web.1]: [db] Cannot read property 'split' of null
2020-05-09T01:57:36.571910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

and when I make a request

```
2020-05-09T02:00:04.559800+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" 
method=GET path="/api/products/list" host=cheapandnice-backend.herokuapp.com 
request_id=98822b44-b339-48ec-b33d-c7dd91e8a380 fwd="186.168.187.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 
service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

I'm using Mongo Atlas

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out it's not a CORS problem. *Heroku logs --tails* shows this

```
2020-05-09T01:57:35.629379+00:00 app[web.1]: [db] Cannot read property 'split' of null
```

I put simple quotes when I configured my ENV variables in heroku

```
'mongodb+srv://...'
```

I removed the quotes and it works now